# Add code syntax (like @data) to index

Tags: symbols, makeindex

I wanted to be able to add some programming syntax to the index of my document like @data.  If I use `index{data!@data}` nothing shows up in the index.  Can you tell me how to get this symbol-text into the index?  Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
This is where the word data\index{data} first appears.
\newpage
I wanted to add this \texttt{@data}\index{data!@data} (with symbol) to also appear under this data index.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure, is `@` an special character for makeindex? If so, you need to escape it.

Comment: It appears that `@` is a special character in makeindex.  How do I go about "escaping" it?

Comment: Try using `"@`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape it by using the quote character which is `"`. So your entry has to be `\index{data!"@data}`.

[image: index]